# Index Error in python code for csv to mp3

Tags: python, csv, indexing, mp3, playlist

[image]

I'm running a code that download the songs from youtube and converts into mp3. but it's showing index error.

Comment: Please add code and error message as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Th error should be clear. You try to access `div[0]`, but there is no entry at index 0. In other words: the list `div` is empty.